# How do I reformat column/row placement in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as shown:

[image]

I would like to remove the 'Category_2' and 'Category_1' from the dataframe. I would also like the dataframe to look like a table, rather than how it is now (state and primary_or_piggyback are both numpy arrays). How would I go about achieving this goal?

Comment: Write the stuff in the image in your question. Some people can't view pictures, and it is just easier to read as text.

Answer (score 0):

Categories one and two are the names of the  index and columns objects respectively.

```
variations_tab.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)
```